# Can I iterate thru a Node List of audio elements to change any that are paused to currentTime = 0

Tags: for-loop, html5-audio, nodelist

I'm trying to make a table of 180 tunes, each tune has an audio element. Once I play the tune and hit the play button again to pause it I want the currentTime to go back to zero.

This isn't working:

```
        const myAudio = document.getElementsByClassName ("myAudio");
        for (let i=0; i<myAudio.length; i++)
        myAudio[i].addEventListener("pause", (event) => {
            myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        }
```

Comment: `myAudio` is a `HTMLCollection`, it does not have `.currentTime`. You probably meant to write `event.target.currentTime` instead of `myAudio.currentTime`? Closing as typo.

Comment: Changed myAudio.currentTime to event.target.currentTime but still it's not working. Any more hints would be very welcome.

Comment: In that case, it is an additional problem. What does "not working" mean? Is there an error message? If you put a `console.log` or a breakpoint into the handler, does it get executed?

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty new to javascript... I know it's not working because when I play an audio player with the class "myAudio" then pause it the counter doesn't reset to 0. Is it even possible to iterate thru a node list to add an event listener to each one?

Comment: I have created a button that calls a function to tell me how many elements have the class "myAudio" and that does work... so it looks like the node list is being created at least!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your "not working" claim. Your code (with the above change) [works](https://jsbin.com/kuzuzapuca/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Make sure your code is a [example], that it faithfully reproduces your problem. Also, if you are a beginner in JavaScript, make sure you read through [this link](https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome), it will give you a solid foundation on how to debug JavaScript programs.

Comment: Is this still closed? If so, can it be opened back up since it was less a typo than a lack of knol

Comment: It only has a close vote, it is not closed.